# Mirror and Merge are not working together

Tags: mirror

so I was trying to merge eyes with my mesh and for some reason, it doesn't work. The mirrored object disappears. I saw on a site that you merge 2 objects with ctrl+J command and it sometimes crashes my blender.

Comment: You may need to apply the mirror modifier before joining the two. If you're merging the eyes with a mesh that does not have a matching mirror modifier, the mirror will not be automatically applied, and the mirror part of the mesh will be lost.

Comment: I am having a different problem now, every time I try to merge them, blender just crashes. I started looking at RAM and it seems like blender takes around 100mb/s more neverending even after more than 10gbs of RAM. Then it just crashes my pc.

Comment: After a few tries, my program didn't crash and now everything is working as it should. Thanks for your quick response!